# List rows of table not containing specific value in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables and I need SQL query witch will select idb, name from basic table exclude where we do not have linked for example yellow.

```
basic_table:
idb... name ... value 
1      color    red   
2      style    modern    

second_table
id ... idb ... second 
1      1       green
2      1       yellow
3      2       red   
4      2       blue
```

Result should be:

```
idb... name
2      style
```

This query will include idp 1 because we have it with green, but should be excluded.

```
SELECT
    `basic_table`.`idp`, `basic_table`.`name`
FROM
`basic_table`
    LEFT JOIN `second_table` 
        ON (`basic_table`.`idp` = `second_table`.`idp`)
WHERE (`second_table`.`second` NOT LIKE '%yellow%')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this using `not exists`:

```
select idb,
    name
from basic_table b
where not exists (
        select 1
        from second_table s
        where b.idb = s.idb
            and s.second = 'yellow'
        );
```

Using left join:

```
select distinct b.idb,
    b.name
from basic_table b
left join second_table s on b.idb = s.idb
    and s.second = 'yellow'
where s.idb is null;
```

Comment: Thanks. First query works, but second does not (it is still displaying first row).